Expressed of Lie-product
Let $A$ be a non-abelian algebra based on field of prime number. Set $[x,y]=xy-yx$ where $x,y\in A$. Can $[x^p,y]$ be expressed as  Linearly combination of Lie-product of $x,y$.

Linear combination of what? $[x, y]$ is just one thing, and $[x^p, y]$ doesn't depend only on $[x, y]$.

I think you can consult the definition of a restricted Lie algebra. I guess the defining property $\mathrm{ad}(X)^p=\mathrm{ad}(X^{[p]})$ is what you are looking for.

"algebra" probably means "associative algebra"? "prime number" probably means "prime characteristic $p$"? "linearly combination" should be "linear combination".

yes，associative algebra，characteristic p and linear combination
